# Long click also triggers regular click

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android: Why does long click also trigger a normal click?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5428077/android-why-does-long-click-also-trigger-a-normal-click)

Duplicate of [Android: Why does long click also trigger a normal click?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5428077/android-why-does-long-click-also-trigger-a-normal-click) and [LongClick event also triggers Click event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/742171/longclick-event-also-triggers-click-event), but those don't contain a solution to my problem.

My OnLongClickListener returns `true`, but I'm still getting OnClick after it, same is I return false. Why?